# Solving a one-dimensional wave equation with d'Alembert's formula

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Consider the one-dimensional wave equation $u_{tt}-u_{xx} = 0$ with boundary conditions $u(x,0) = g(x) = x^2$ and $u_t(x,0) = h(x) = 1- x^2$.
I am trying to apply d'Alembert's formula and et
$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2}[(x+t)^2+(x-t)^2] + \frac{1}{2} \int^{x+t}_{x-t} (1-y^2) dy = ... = x^2 + t^2 + t - x^2 - \frac{1}{3} t^3$. But this neither solves the equation nor the satisfies the boundary conditions. What went wrong?

Comment: In fact, d'Alemblert's formula produces $u(x,t)=x^2+t^2+t-t^3/3-tx^2.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following commands can be used to solve the problem with the use of Maple:

> g := x-> x^2; h := x-> 1-x^2;
>
> simplify( 1/2*(g(x-t)+g(x+t)) + 1/2*int( h(xi), xi=x-t .. x+t) );

Maple will respond with

> $\displaystyle x^2+t^2+t-\frac{t^3}3-tx^2$

(I'd recommend my [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MZ1LDYS) on PDEs in which numerous
examples are given how to handle PDEs with the use of Maple and Wolfram Alpha.)